# Mysql select and order by id but premium users on top

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I'm trying make app for users and there is 2 groups of users. Normal and Premium. I have list where are they all. But I want to order they by id desc and then premium users will be on top. So if I had the normal users id 1,4,5,6,7 and the premium users had id 2,3 they will be on top of the list. How can I achieve this with simple mysql select? Or any simple code.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC AND ORDER BY premium .. ?
```

Comment: Read the mysql manual on `ORDER BY` you can use two columns to sort on, but not like you do it. Simply use something like: `ORDER BY id DESC, premium ASC.

Comment: share some dummy data,and i would seggust, you should have a separate feild for premium as bool

Comment: What value does the `premium` column contain for these 2 conditions